# Can not fetch value from REST service in AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, resources, ngresource

I'm trying fetch data by calling Java REST service from AngularJS web portal. I'm using ngResource.

Call From Angular Service :

```
BankingModule.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/demoApp/service/users', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
    })
});
```

It is calling Service perfectly and even I can get the result if I put the URL directly at the browser :

```
URL :   http://localhost:8080/demoApp/service/users

RESULT :   [{"id":1,"firstName":"Jayanta","lastName":"Pramanik"}]
```

But Angular-JS controller I can not get any result !!

For your understanding -
Here is my Service method definition -

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getAllUsersInJSON() {
    /* ------ Some Hard coded values are set into an ArrayList ------*/
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    User usr1 = new User();
    usr1.setId(1);
    usr1.setFirstName("Jayanta");
    usr1.setLastName("Pramanik");

    userList.add(usr1);

    return userList;
}
```

Any idea please !

Thanks in advance -

Jayanta P.

Comment: where is your .js file?

Comment: what web server are you using that you serves up your angular application? Are you redirecting to localhost:8080 or have you set up CORS settings in the web server?